# While Loop returning name error but works on some online IDE's?

Tags: python, while-loop, nameerror

I have a simple while loop that appends numbers from user input into a list:

```
#establish the list variables
a = []

#takes user input until user types done
print("Please enter multiple numbers to put on a list:\n(type 'done' when finished)")
while True:
    user_input = input()
    if user_input == "done":
        break
    user_input = int(user_input)
    a.append(user_input)
print(a)
```

The error occurs in line 8 : **if user_input == "done"**

Error comes back as : **NameError: name 'done' is not defined**

It seems to work in other IDE's for some reason. Im currently running it in Python version 2.7 in Pycharm and keeps returning the error.

Why is it telling me this? Is it my python version thats effecting this?

Comment: Which IDE is it failing in?  Give example of IDE that it works on

Comment: Suggest you to switch to Python3.x,  Python2. is `sunset` already.

Comment: Its failing on pycharm but works on https://www.online-python.com/ or https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/. I think its my python version.

Comment: Yeah I was working on my laptop instead of computer and I didn't have python updated on it lol.

Answer (score 0):

In python 2, `input` takes a command instead of an input, you need instead:

```
user_input = raw_input()
```